# Issue with Loading In-App Purchase Dialog

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have recetly added iap in my app but dont know why im no getting any dialog i have followed this blog

https://programtown.com/how-to-make-in-app-purchase-in-android-using-google-play-billing-library/

but with some modifiation

```
public class Image_PostFragment extends Fragment implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    private final String premiumProductId = "com.dummyDevName.AppName.productid_premium";
    MaterialButton  Premium_ImgPostTab;
    AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener ackPurchase = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // Acknowledgment successful
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Acknowledgment successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Handle acknowledgment error
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Acknowledgment unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    // IAP
    private BillingClient billingClient;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_post_tab, container, false);
        //Var Initialization
       
        Premium_ImgPostTab = view.findViewById(R.id.buyPremium_ImgPostTab);
       


        // Initialize BillingClient
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext()).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this) // Use "this" if Image_PostFragment is implementing PurchasesUpdatedListener
                .build();

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // You can query purchases here if needed
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Handle disconnection
            }
        });



        // Buy Premium Btn Click
        Premium_ImgPostTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (billingClient.isReady()) {
                    purchase(v);
                } else {
                    // Handle BillingClient not ready
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Unable to load win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

     //initiate purchase on button click
    public void purchase(View view) {
        //check if service is already connected
        if (billingClient.isReady()) {
            initiatePurchase();
        }
        //else reconnect service
        else {
            billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext()).enablePendingPurchases().setListener((PurchasesUpdatedListener) requireContext()).build();
            billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        initiatePurchase();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error " + billingResult.getDebugMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void initiatePurchase() {
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(premiumProductId);
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size() > 0) {
                        BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0)).build();
                        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), flowParams);
                    } else {
                        // Handle case where SKU details are not available
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
        Log.d("Billing", "onPurchasesUpdated: Response Code: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());

        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
            Log.d("Billing", "onPurchasesUpdated: Loading Ad");
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Loading Ad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handlePurchases(purchases);
        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
            Log.d("Billing", "onPurchasesUpdated: Already Owned");
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Already Owned ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            Log.d("Billing", "onPurchasesUpdated: Purchase Canceled");
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Purchase Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("Billing", "onPurchasesUpdated: Unknown Error");
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Unknown Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    // Handle Purchase
    private void handlePurchases(List<Purchase> purchases) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            if (premiumProductId.equals(purchase.getSkus()) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                // Handle valid purchase
                if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken()).build();
                    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, ackPurchase);
                } else {
                    // Purchase is acknowledged, check if it's not yet saved in SharedPreferences
                    if (!getPurchaseValueFromPref()) {
                        // Save purchase status to SharedPreferences
                        savePurchaseValueToPref(true);
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Item Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        requireActivity().recreate();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Handle other purchase states (PENDING, UNSPECIFIED_STATE)
        }
    }

    // Get purchase value from SharedPreferences
    private boolean getPurchaseValueFromPref() {
        return mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false);
    }

    // Save purchase value to SharedPreferences
    private void savePurchaseValueToPref(boolean value) {
        mSharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, value).apply();
    }
}
```

i have also added the Security.java file as mention in the article mentioned

```
public class Security {
    private static final String TAG = "IABUtil/Security";

    private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withRSA";

    /**
     * Verifies that the data was signed with the given signature, and returns the verified
     * purchase.
     * @param base64PublicKey the base64-encoded public key to use for verifying.
     * @param signedData the signed JSON string (signed, not encrypted)
     * @param signature the signature for the data, signed with the private key
     * @throws IOException if encoding algorithm is not supported or key specification
     * is invalid
     */
    public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData,
                                         String signature) throws IOException {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey)
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
            //Purchase verification failed: missing data
            return false;
        }

        PublicKey key = generatePublicKey("added the key from monitization>license");
        return verify(key, signedData, signature);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a PublicKey instance from a string containing the Base64-encoded public key.
     *
     * @param encodedPublicKey Base64-encoded public key
     * @throws IOException if encoding algorithm is not supported or key specification
     * is invalid
     */
    public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
            return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // "RSA" is guaranteed to be available.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            String msg = "Invalid key specification: " + e;
            throw new IOException(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the signature from the server matches the computed signature on the data.
     * Returns true if the data is correctly signed.
     *
     * @param publicKey public key associated with the developer account
     * @param signedData signed data from server
     * @param signature server signature
     * @return true if the data and signature match
     */
    public static boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
        byte[] signatureBytes;
        try {
            signatureBytes = Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //Base64 decoding failed
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Signature signatureAlgorithm = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
            signatureAlgorithm.initVerify(publicKey);
            signatureAlgorithm.update(signedData.getBytes());
            if (!signatureAlgorithm.verify(signatureBytes)) {
                //Signature verification failed
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // "RSA" is guaranteed to be available
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            //Invalid key specification
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            //Signature exception
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please note that i have added both keys properly the product id and the Base64-encoded RSA public key

and cross verified 3 times , there is no issue with the keys in particlaur

Comment: With billing client 6.0.1, you have to set offerToken for skudetails. can you check if you have added the offer token ? i don't see it in the code you posted above.